# Linux RSS Feed Notifier/Ticker

Tags: linux, rss

Looking for an app to popup notifications every time a new feed item is added. Clicking the notification should open in the default browser.

Can't seem to find anything, seems like there *has* to be one out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is! [RSSnotifier](https://rssnotifier.dev.java.net/) is written in Java and I used it on my XP box for a while. Notifications will open in the current browser when clicked.

Comment: Little on the ugly side, but it works as needed. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah that's the downside. I changed mine to use the system look and feel so it matched Windows, the same should work for GNOME.

Comment: Whatever they feel the 'system' notifier of GNOME is looks even worse. (Note: Other apps using the 'system' notifier do not.) Perhaps some of the changes made to GNOME's notification system in newer versions will help (I'm running Ubuntu 8.10 on this system).

Answer (score 7):

Try [newsbeuter](http://www.newsbeuter.org/). It's a very flexible and lightweight console application that can easily handle desktop notifications. Just add these lines in `${HOME}/.newsbeuter/config`

```
notify-program notify-send
notify-always yes
```

Additionally, you can control the format of the string in the notification but unfortunately clicking the notification won't open links in the default browser. See [newsbeuter documentation](http://www.newsbeuter.org/doc/newsbeuter.html) and [this](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-get-notifications-your-scripts-notify-send) article for more info on newsbeuter and notify-send.

Since you are running Ubuntu 8.10 you will get an old version of newsbeuter via apt-get. To install the latest 2.0, follow these steps:

- download [newsbeuter-2.0](http://www.newsbeuter.org/downloads/newsbeuter-2.0.tar.gz)
- extract the tar.gz archive:

  ```
  tar xvzf newsbeuter-2.0.tar.gz
  ```
- install needed dependencies:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install libstfl-dev libsqlite3-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev libxml2-dev gettext
  ```
- Compile and install newsbeuter:

  ```
  make && sudo make install
  ```
- Import your feed list using:

  ```
  newsbeuter -i feedlist.opml
  ```
- Enjoy your new feed reader!

Comment: Love that it's console based. Opening the link on notification is really the limitation of notify-send.

Comment: Notify-send notifications can contain "clickable" web links if the body of the message contains an html style reference (<a href="...">...</a>). So, in theory, it would be possible to hack the source of newsbeuter to handle per-article notifications with link to the web source.

Comment: For people coming here from the future, this project is no longer maintained, but was forked and still developed under the name of [newsboat](https://newsboat.org/)

Answer (score 0):

[Yarssr](http://yarssr.sourceforge.net/)

RSS reader for the notification areaYet Another RSS Reader is an RSS aggregator and reader that displays its results in the GNOME or KDE system tray (notification area). To view the contents of the feed just click the menu-item and it will launch in your favorite browser.

[image]

Comment: I think hes looking for a notifier rather than a full blown reader

Comment: I'm actually running that now, and while the interface is nice, it lacks (as far as I can tell) any kind of popup notification.